# JavaFX ListView not active

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a problem with JavaFX ListView. 
I have three of them and want to be able to drag and drop custom objects between them. There is no problem with that if at least one item is in the destination list. If there is none, the drag and drop can't be completed. The cursor changes from default mouse to a crossed circle.

Also if the listview has no elements the list looks 'plain', if there is one or more it looks 'normal' with striped background.

Here is my code:
Controller.java

```
public class Controller
{
private final ObjectProperty<ListCell<Task>> dragSource = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
@FXML
public ListView<Task> listView1;
@FXML
public ListView<Task> listView2;
@FXML
public ListView<Task> listView3;

public ObservableList<Task> toDoList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public ObservableList<Task> inProgressList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public ObservableList<Task> doneList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private boolean isDragSuccessful;
private Task currentTask = null;
private ListView<Task> currentListView;

public void closeApp()
{
    Platform.exit();
}

public void openTaskAddingWindow()
{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TaskAddWindow.fxml"));

    Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    try
    {
        stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TaskAddWindow controller = loader.getController();
    stage.setResizable(false);

    controller.init(currentListView, currentTask);
    stage.setTitle("Add new Task");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(400);
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event ->
    {
        stage.close();
        event.consume();
    });

    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.showAndWait();

}

public void createCellFactory(ListView<Task> listView, ObservableList<Task> list)
{
    listView.setItems(list);
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

    listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Task>, ListCell<Task>>()
    {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Task> call(ListView<Task> param)
        {
            final ListCell<Task> cell = new ListCell<Task>()
            {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Task item, boolean empty)
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                        setText(item.getTaskName());
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            };

            cell.setOnDragDetected(event ->
            {

                if (!cell.isEmpty())
                {
                    isDragSuccessful = false;
                    Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                    ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
                    Task tt = cell.getItem();
                    cc.putString(tt.getTaskName());
                    db.setContent(cc);
                    dragSource.set(cell);
                }
            });

            cell.setOnDragOver(event ->
            {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                if (db.hasString())
                {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }

            });

            cell.setOnDragDone(event ->
            {
                if (isDragSuccessful)
                    listView.getItems().remove(cell.getItem());
                ;
            });

            cell.setOnDragDropped(event ->
            {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                if (db.hasString() && dragSource.get() != null)
                {
                    ListCell<Task> dragSourceCell = dragSource.get();
                    listView.getItems().add(dragSourceCell.getItem());
                    isDragSuccessful = true; // This is here beacuse the line under this one, doesn't work
                    event.setDropCompleted(true);
                    dragSource.set(null);
                } else
                {
                    event.setDropCompleted(false);
                }
            });

            return cell;
        }

    }); // setCellFactory

}//createCellFactory  ---- end

public void initialize()
{
    createCellFactory(listView1, toDoList);
    createCellFactory(listView2, inProgressList);
    createCellFactory(listView3, doneList);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        listView2.getItems().add(new Task("2+" + i, "LOW", LocalDate.now(), ""));
        listView3.getItems().add(new Task("3+" + i, "LOW", LocalDate.now(), ""));
    }
    currentListView = listView1;
}
}
```

[This is how the lists look both empty and with elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmztZ.png)

I tried searching the internet for similar problems, but to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drag handlers are registered with the `ListCell`s. As you can see from the appearance of the `ListView`, when the `ListView` is empty, no `ListCell`s are displayed; consequently there is nothing to handle the drag events.

You just need to register handlers with the individual list views as well, to handle dropping onto an empty list view:

```
private void configureListViewDragAndDrop(ListView<?> listView) {

    listView.setOnDragOver(event ->
    {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasString())
        {
            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
        }
        event.consume();
    });

    listView.setOnDragDropped(event ->
    {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasString() && dragSource.get() != null)
        {
            ListCell<Task> dragSourceCell = dragSource.get();
            listView.getItems().add(dragSourceCell.getItem());
            isDragSuccessful = true; // This is here beacuse the line under this one, doesn't work
            event.setDropCompleted(true);
            dragSource.set(null);
        } else
        {
            event.setDropCompleted(false);
        }
        event.consume();
    });

}
```

and then of course

```
public void initialize() {

    // existing code...

    Stream.of(listView1, listView2, listView3)
          .forEach(this::configureListViewDragAndDrop);

}
```

Finally, you should consume the drag events on the list cells, to ensure that the same event is never handled both by the cells and the list view itself.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. The solution was sooo simple. Thanks a lot!